# Is there any design tool for C programming language?

Tags: c

Is there any design tool for C programming language?

Note that I use C not C++ and I want to use a design tool something like [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/), But it seems UML is not a good way for C, because C is not an object oriented language.

What is the best method for designing the C based application and libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that C can still be used to implement the Object Oriented paradigm however it takes more work than in C++.

Comment: UML is still fine. That C isn't objective doesn't mean, that you don't have objects and interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post, it is similar

[How to design an UML class diagramm with non object oriented parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226640/how-to-design-an-uml-class-diagramm-with-non-object-oriented-parts)

Answer (score 1):

Have a read here about how to better use uml for C: http://drdobbs.com/web-development/184401948

Also read this question, it has some good answers: [UML for C programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042608/uml-for-c-programming-language)